# reg ex to match ALL not enclosing quotation marks.

Tags: regex

Having kind of this line:  (example of a line in a wannabe CSV)

`""",100,""a"sa",""," "","" ","a"z","a"",""z","""",""",200,"a"a",""`

I want a regex that match all quotation mark `"` that are not enclosing the strings... (to remove them in a later stage and build a 100% compliant CSV)

I came up with this partial solution: `(?<!,)"(?!,)` using negative lookbehind and lookahead to match only not enclosing `"`

It almost made the trick but the very first character and the last one of each line, both `"`, are matched too by the regex.

example: https://regexr.com/41kve

I want a regex that workaround this so first and last character are not part of the matching regex

Some ideas how to do it?

Comment: Try `(?<!,|^)"(?!\s*(?:,|$))`

Comment: There is a trailing space in your regexr sample, but not in your post. Will there be some in your actual data?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew that was the answer alternate inside the lookbehind/ahead group... so easy :D thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!,|^)"(?!\s*(?:,|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UeixQG/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!,|^)` - no start of string or comma immediately to the left of the current location
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(?!\s*(?:,|$))` - no `,` or end of string preceded with 0+ whitespaces immediately to the right of the current location.